# R printing each data.frame of a list into separate Tables with caption as data.frame name and description

Tags: r, tidyverse, knitr, purrr, kableextra

**Follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71286570/707145).**  (Thanks to @akrun for his help.)

Want to print each `data.frame` of a list into separate Tables with caption as `data.frame` name and description from another object. My attempted code is given below. Not being able to get description in tables caption.

**What am I missing here?**

If this is working:

```
Names1 %>% 
      filter(Name == quote(df1)) %>% 
      pull(Desp)
```

Why is this not working inside `imap`?

```
Names1 %>% 
 filter(Name == quote(.y)) %>% 
 pull(Desp)
```

**Complete Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'kableExtra'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     group_rows

df1 <- data.frame(X = 1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(Y = 5:6)

ls1 <-
  list(df1, df2) %>% 
  set_names(c("df1", "df2"))

ls1
#> $df1
#>   X
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 
#> $df2
#>   Y
#> 1 5
#> 2 6

Names1 <- 
  tibble(
    Name = c("df1", "df2")
  , Desp = c("Desp1", "Desp2")
  )

Names1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Name  Desp 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 df1   Desp1
#> 2 df2   Desp2

Names1 %>% 
  filter(Name == quote(df1)) %>% 
  pull(Desp)
#> [1] "Desp1"


imap(
    .x = ls1
  , .f = ~ {
    kbl(
       x       = .x
     , format  = "markdown"
     , caption = paste0("Test ", .y, " ( ", 
                        Names1 %>% 
                          filter(Name == quote(.y)) %>% 
                          pull(Desp)
                        , " )"
                        )
    )
    }
  )
#> $df1
#> 
#> 
#> Table: Test df1 (  )
#> 
#> |  X|
#> |--:|
#> |  1|
#> |  2|
#> |  3|
#> 
#> $df2
#> 
#> 
#> Table: Test df2 (  )
#> 
#> |  Y|
#> |--:|
#> |  5|
#> |  6|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.y` is already quoted within `imap` as is seen by the output of the first part of `paste0("Test ", .y, " ( ",` which returns `Table: Test df1 (` so you don't need quote.

Note:

```
Names1 %>% 
  filter(Name == "df1") %>% 
  pull(Desp)
# [1] "Desp1"
```

so if you don't include quote it works:

```
imap(
  .x = ls1
  , .f = ~ {
    kbl(
      x       = .x
      , format  = "markdown"
      , caption = paste0("Test ", .y, " ( ", 
                         Names1 %>% 
                           filter(Name == .y) %>% 
                           pull(Desp)
                         , " )"
      )
    )
  }
)
# $df1


# Table: Test df1 ( Desp1 )

# |  X|
# |--:|
# |  1|
# |  2|
# |  3|

# $df2


# Table: Test df2 ( Desp2 )

# |  Y|
# |--:|
# |  5|
# |  6|
```

The way you were doing it, it was filtering for something that wasn't in the data.frame (`.y`). See here:

```
imap(
  .x = ls1
  , .f = ~ {
    .y
  }
)
# $df1
# [1] "df1"

# $df2
# [1] "df2"


imap(
  .x = ls1
  , .f = ~ {
    quote(.y)
  }
)
# $df1
# .y

# $df2
# .y
```